# Convert number to 0 padded string

Tags: sql-server, time, ssms, concatenation

```
CASE 
   WHEN LEN(TIME1) = 3 THEN (RIGHT('0' + CAST(TIME1 AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)) 
END AS TIME1
```

This code works, because when value is 812, it will return 0812. But sometimes it is 1012, so the value is returned as null.

I wrote

```
CASE 
   WHEN LEN(TIME1) = 3 
      THEN (RIGHT('0' + CAST(TIME1 AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)) 
      ELSE TIME1 
END AS TIME1
```

But this just gives me 812 and 1012 all over again.

I am trying to convert it to 4 char so I can convert it to hh:mm and then concat with date column.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server (based on the SSMS tag) then the "normal" way to get a number with leading zeroes would be like this:

```
RIGHT('0000'+CONVERT(varchar(4),YourColumn),4)
```

You could use `REPLICATE` for a more scalable, or parametrisable, version:

```
RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',4)+CONVERT(varchar(4),YourColumn),4)
```

You can also use `CONCAT` to avoid to explicit conversion:

```
RIGHT(CONCAT(REPLICATE('0',4),YourColumn),4)
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. Replicate seems a bit more complicated for my level of knowledge haha.

Are you suggesting to use replicate to make process faster? So it doesn't convert unless there is a need?

Comment: No, the suggestion is for a scalable or parametrisable version, @plshelpimpoor (as I mention in the answer). It's also easier when you have larger numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the value to a string.  But you don't really need a `case` at all.  Just use:

```
RIGHT('0' + CAST(TIME1 as VARCHAR(4)), 4)
```

This will work for both 3 and 4 characters.

You can expand this to:

```
RIGHT('0000' + CAST(TIME1 as VARCHAR(4)), 4)
```

And it will work for 0-4 chararacters.